# How to show value on ng-click event?

Tags: angularjs

I am bit new to AngularJs and looking for help on some basic concepts.
Basically the following code correctly shows data returned from request API.

**Request.cshtml**

```
<div data-ng-controller="PostsController">
    <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
    <strong data-ng-show="loading">loading..</strong>

    <div data-ng-repeat="request in posts | orderBy: 'Id':true">

        <strong>ID: {{ request.Id }}</strong>
        <strong>Contact No: {{ request.ContactNumber }}</strong>
    </div>

</div>
```

now i am further looking to add button in view and when user click on in, the contact number should be displayed.
i have written following html/angular view code.
show number

**I need help in writing the corresponding "ShowNumber()" function in PostsController.js file.
But i am confused how to send single value instead of lists. Any help on it please?**

here is my current PostsController.js code

```
function PostsController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.editMode = false;

    $http.get('/api/request').success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
        $scope.loading = false;
    });



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The function:**

```
$scope.ShowNumber=function(value){  
  //Your logic
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Show" ng-click="ShowNumber(request.Id)" />
```

You can send any value in the function.
Also you can send a index of list:

```
ng-click="ShowNumber($index)"
```

Comment: Hi Norbert Pisz, i am in fact facing problem how to send back single record to HTML from AngularJs Controller.

Comment: $scope.ShowNumber=function(value){  
         var index = getRequestID(value);
          // The index of record found at above line, how can i send   it back to HTML?
    }

Comment: Here you have dynamic binding. So you can use any dynamic value from $scope in HTML.